# TextFormField borderSide color is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, border, textfield

I'm trying to add the color on border, but it's not working, please check where i'm doing wrong.

Here is my code

```dart
  passwordtext() {
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        child: Focus(
          focusNode: myFocusNode,
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: HexColor("#d8d6de"))),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                
          ),
        ));
  }
```

When I tap on the field border color changes which I want it also without tap on it

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you exact want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `enabledBorder` on `InputDecoration`

```dart
TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)), // your color
          ),
        ),
```

More about [InputDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. refer enabled border [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/enabledBorder.html)

```
 Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            child: Focus(
              focusNode: myFocusNode,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Your result screen before focus- [image]

Your screen after focus -> [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Change your input decoration(For TextFormField) like the code given below**

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffd8d6de))),
                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffd8d6de))),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffd8d6de))),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffd8d6de))),
                ),
```

*Give the focusedBorder, disabledBorder and enabledBorder same properts so everytime the textformfiled looks same.*

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add enabledBorder on InputDecoration add this to your code

```
enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
      ),
      child: Text('MyBorder'),
    )
```

Comment: but i want the borderRadius too and want to do it in InputDecoration

Comment: Do you want container borderRadius or TextFormField borderRadius

Comment: TextFormField , it is done by using enableBorder instead Border